# Select rows not in another table for each condition of a field in the other table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

Agents with columns: agentid, name

DocumentsRead with columns: agentid, document, dateread

I need to identify all the agents who have not read each document in the documentsread table. So if Agents holds 10 records and in DocumentsRead I have 5 records showing doc1 has been read and 4 records showing doc2 has been read my expected result should have 11 records in it. 5 showing the agents that have not read doc1 and 6 showing the agents that have not read doc2.

I understand how to use various queries to identify that records in Agents don't exist in DocumentsRead but I can't figure out how to make this work for each Document that is listed in DocumentsRead.

Comment: Do you have a `Documents` table?  Is there some other way to determine that there are documents that no one has read yet, e.g. they are assigned to agents in `DocumentsRead`, but with NULL `dateread`?

Comment: There is no Documents table. I.e. we only know who has read a document. If a document exists then all agents should read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Agents, (SELECT DISTINCT document FROM DocumentsRead) docs 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM DocumentsRead 
    WHERE agentid = Agents.agentid AND document = docs.document
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
SELECT AG.AgentId, DOC.document
FROM Agents AG, 
(select document from DocumentsRead) DOC
except 
select DOC1.AgentId, DOC1.document from DocumentsRead DOC1
```

The idea is:

a) Get the table for case if every agent would read every document:

```
SELECT AG.AgentId, DOC.document
FROM Agents AG, 
(select distinct document from DocumentsRead) DOC
```

b) Get the documents that already read by agents:

```
select distinct DOC1.AgentId, DOC1.document from DocumentsRead DOC1
```

c) Exclude (b) from (a) using `except` (and in this case `distinct` is not needed already)

Comment: Should work, I think. Perhaps, `DISTINCT` is unnecessary, because it is implied by `EXCEPT`.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe this (same as [@socha23's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9888119), only uses `LEFT JOIN + WHERE IS NULL` instead of `NOT EXISTS`):

```
SELECT
  a.agentid,
  a.name,
  d.document
FROM Agents a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT document FROM DocumentsRead) d
  LEFT JOIN DocumentsRead r ON a.agentid = r.agentid AND d.document = r.document
WHERE r.agentid IS NULL
```